# AS - WHERE not working

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT *,(SELECT count(*) FROM resimler WHERE ilanId=ilanlar.Id) AS
 sayi FROM ilanlar WHERE sayi>0
```

Error : #1054 - Unknown column 'sayi' in 'where clause' –

Comment: Hello. Can you add some details to your question, stating what you have tried, what result you want to achieve and what specifically you have found is not working.

Comment: your reply does not mean anything to me. Please use prose and proper language to describe your issue. Use Google translate if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behavior.  Column aliases are not recognized in the `SELECT` or `WHERE` clauses where they are defined.

One option is to use a MySQL extension, and replace the `WHERE` clause with:

```
HAVING sayi > 0
```

In your case, though, I'd probably just use a `JOIN` and explicit `GROUP BY`:

```
select i.id, count(*)
from ilanlar i join
     resimler r
     on r.ilanid = i.id
group by i.id;
```